# Reactjs call component/function from built app

Tags: reactjs

I had built a modular web application: user install core app and had plugin module (it's batch of files) to a folder, core auto-discover it and add menu and component.

Actually, it's php/jquery/bootstrap and I want to rewrite it with Reactjs (for frontend). Unfortunately, I can't find how can I conserve this modular system with Reactjs. What I need :

- core will display page and call for some part of this page a
  component from the plugin (like a row of the table) core will display
- sort of dashboard with the widget, I need for some widgets, a
  component from the plugin core can display panel and this panel is
  built by the plugin, but the plugin can use some JS from core to do
  it
- I can not rebuild Reactjs app after plugin install, the only way
  is to build react core app and react plugin app separately, then
  after install include built version of apps

I search but I can't find the example of this usage, can you help me on this?

Thank in advance for your time/help

Answer (score 1):

There is no clean way to do this in a standard react-build stack.
What you can do in to user React avoid building processes.
This can bring to performace issues and the process is not straightforward as the react community ecosystem is based on build webpack processes.

```js
// [...]

<script type="text/babel" charset="utf-8">
  // "Import" the components from Reactstrap
  // This can be also an array of components stored in an external file
  const {Button} = Reactstrap;

  // Render a Reactstrap Button element onto root
  ReactDOM.render(
    <Button color="danger">Hello, world!</Button>,
    document.getElementById('root')
  );
</script>

// [...]
```

Ref: https://shinglyu.github.io/web/2018/02/08/minimal-react-js-without-a-build-step-updated.html